# Tracelessness of switching maps

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\theta$ be a linear transformation on a vector space $V$  with the decomposition $V= P \oplus K $ , such that $\theta$ maps $K$ to $P$ and $P$ to $K$, then $\theta$ is traceless. I like to know if there is a way to prove this without taking a base and showing the corresponding matrix is traceless.

Comment: W.r.t. a basis of $V$ gotten by putting together bases for $P$ and $K$ the matrix of $\theta$ has the block form
$$M(\theta)=\pmatrix{0&A\cr B&0\cr}$$ with square shaped zero blocks. This makes the claim kinda clear. May I ask why you don't like this argument?

Comment: I want to know if there are some lemmas that without summoning matrices we can solve easy problems about trace of transformations.

Comment: One needs a basis-free definition of trace to even begin such an argument. One answer is to define it as the sum of eigenvalues (within the algebraic closure of the scalar field if necessary) of a linear operator. Another is to combine certain natural isomorphisms (here $V^*$ means dual space): $${\rm tr}:{\rm End}_k(V)\cong V\otimes_k V^*\to k$$ where $k$ is the base field and the last map acts as $v\otimes \phi\mapsto\phi(v)$ on pure tensors. This route yields a "block matrix" decomposition that doesn't actually require choosing any basis, but is more long-winded than the eigenvalue route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use linearity of the trace. You can decompose $\theta = \theta_{PK} + \theta_{KP}$, where $\theta_{PK}$ maps $P$ to $K$, and $K$ to zero, and similarly for $\theta_{KP}$, with the roles of $P$ and $K$ reversed.

We want to show that the trace of $\theta_{PK}$ is zero. (Clearly the same will hold for $\theta_{KP}$.)

Clearly $\theta_{PK}^{2} = 0$. This implies that all eigenvalues of $\theta_{PK}$ are zero (as the minimal polynomial of $\theta_{PK}$ divides $x^{2}$), hence the trace of $\theta_{PK}$ is zero. (Is one entitled to use the latter argument?)

Comment: yes, I liked your argument.

Comment: For the final argument you could avoid mentioning eigenvalues if you can use the "converse Cayley-Hamilton" theorem that the characteristic polynomial divides a power of the minimal polynomial (because $\chi_\theta$ is the product of the invariant factors associated to $XI-\theta$): in the given situation the characteristic polynomial is therefore a power of $X$, and its subdominant coefficient therefore zero.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, that's brilliant, I wish I had thought of this argument myself!